# My appointment at the US Embassy in Abuja has been cancelled - now what?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa, interview

I have an appointment scheduled for Monday 24th of October 2022 in Abuja, I just got a message which said that my interview had been cancelled without any clue about when I will be rescheduled again. I am based in South Africa and I only came back to Nigeria because of the interview. I don't know if they will reschedule soon, if not I will just have to fly back to my country of residence. Below is the message I got from them.

> Dear Applicant,
>
> The US Embassy in Abuja regrets to inform you that all appointments scheduled between October 24 have been canceled. Affected applicants were notified by email and SMS. The Embassy will reach out to affected applicants with further information.
> We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Help Desk

Comment: I doubt you can do much other than to wait for the embassy to provide the further information it promised in its message

Comment: If you are now in Abuja you could go to the embassy today, as if you haven't yet received the notification, and see if you can obtain any idea about the timescale.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thank you, I got the information I needed, I saw on the news and online that there is an active threat or potential terrorist attack and all schools are closed.

Comment: @Az Recipes Nothing yet from the US Embassy, I just had this feeling that they won't operate this year again probably till next year.

Comment: Pls anyone with any update on US embassy Abuja yet, I was among the affected applicants last year.